# Error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token| with bubbleSort Function

Tags: c, function, bubble-sort

I've been learning C and I've wrote a BubbleSort function, but there's this strange error and I can't figure it out. Sorry if it's too stupid, as I said I'm learning

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 5

void bbsort(int *array,int n)

int main()
{
    int v[N]={1,5,4,2,3};

    bbsort(*v,N); 

    for (int k=0;k<N;k++) {
        printf("%d\t",v[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void bbsort(int *array,int n) {
    int i,j,tmp;

    for (i=1;i<n;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<n-i;j++) {
            if (array[j]>array[j+1]) { 
                tmp=array[j];
                array[j]=array[j+1];
                array[j+1]=tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `;` in your function declaration. Here's how it should look like:

```
void bbsort(int *array,int n);
```

Comment: Please don't post answers only pointing out a typographical issue or a missing character. Such answers are unlikely to help future visitors since they are specific to OP's code. Instead, flag or vote to close the question as off-topic as per the [help/on-topic].